# How to switch to next page in Opera using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, opera

Im creating a javascript and at some point I want it to switch to the next tab/page in opera. That part looks like this:

```
case "O":
    if(document.URL.indexOf("&screen=place&try=confirm") >= 0){ 
        document.forms[0].submit.click();
    }
    else if(document.URL.indexOf("screen=place&target=") >= 0){ 
        insertUnit(document.units.light,30); document.units.attack.click();
    }
    else if(document.URL.indexOf("&screen=place") >= 0){ 
        SWITCH TO NEXT PAGE
    }
    break;
```

Switch to next page of course doesnt work, so my question is, what would work?

Comment: You mean `location='page2.html'` ???

Comment: I actually want it to do the same as the Opera-command: Switch to next Page

Comment: What does it do exactly?

Comment: It switches to the next tab in Opera

Comment: I can imagine that happen only if you opened the tab using script and name: `window.open('somepage.html','windowname');` then you may be able to focus: `var x = window.open('','windowname'); x.focus();`

Comment: Oh thx for your answer, I found a different solution, by taking advantage of opera tab-closing-behavior.

Comment: @JohnAno you can post it as answer and accept.